# Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android

I try to mage Google Cloud Messaging.

I have follow class:

```
package de.phcom.avs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class GcmRegistrationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
private static Registration regService = null;
private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
private Context context;

// TODO: change to your own sender ID to Google Developers Console project number, as per instructions above
private static final String SENDER_ID = "131952017954";

public GcmRegistrationAsyncTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    if (regService == null) {
        Registration.Builder builder = new Registration.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                // Need setRootUrl and setGoogleClientRequestInitializer only for local testing,
                // otherwise they can be skipped
                .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest)
                            throws IOException {
                        abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                    }
                });
        // end of optional local run code

        regService = builder.build();
    }

    String msg = "";
    try {
        if (gcm == null) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        }
        String regId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
        msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;

        // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
        // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
        // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
        // is using accounts.
        regService.register(regId).execute();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        msg = "Error: " + ex.getMessage();
    }
    return msg;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Logger.getLogger("REGISTRATION").log(Level.INFO, msg);
}
}
```

and they say:

- Cannot resolve symbol 'Registration'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'AndroidHttp'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'AndroidJsonFactory'

and so on.
I have downloaded Google API 19 and 21.

Comment: You don't seem to be importing any of those.

Comment: they don't find any imoports

Comment: Check the dependencies in your project. I.e. the google-http-java-client.

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Comment: the code is from: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints

Answer (score 2):

Just elaborating Mena's answer

You can fix this by adding the following dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.22.0'
```